# How to not select data from a column based on a condition during a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My apologies if my question looks odd, hopefully when I explain it then it will be understandable...

I have this select statement

```
select 
    cax.CustomerID,
    cax.AddressID,
    c.YearBuilt,
    a.Line1,
    a.Line2,
    a.City,
    a.ZipCode,
    a.StateID,
    a.SubDivision,
    s.Directions
from [CustomerAddressXREF] cax
inner join [Customer] c on c.CustomerID = cax.CustomerID
inner join [Address] a on a.AddressID = cax.AddressID
inner join [SubDivision] s on s.SubDivisionName = a.SubDivision
where cax.CustomerID = 11
```

and its returning the following data
[image: returned data]

I know the issue is laying in the SubDivision column. If I comment out the a.SubDivision and s.Directions then I get 1 row returned, which is what it should be based on the statement. What I would like to do is if a.SubDivision = N/A, then I don't want to include it in the query or the s.Directions.

I have no idea where to start or where to begin to pull this off. Is it possible to do what I am looking to do

**EDIT**

The result I am looking for is this

[image: Expected result]

So if SubDivision column contains N/A then it won't select the SubDivision or Directions

Comment: Just add this in your WHERE clause: `AND s.subdivision <> 'N/A'`

Comment: @scsimon I asked for the sample data coz I thought OP can't be asking *this*. :D

Comment: @GurwinderSingh  I reread it a few times because I thought the same thing but don't see it any other way

Comment: Edit has been made, hopefully its more clearer

Comment: One solution I have thought of would be to count the rows from the query, if its more than one then run a different statement without the Subdivisions and Directions and return that data, or if its one row returned then return that data. Not sure how to do that though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what result you want returned, so we're just making guesses.

Based on the specification, to omit values of `a.SubDivision` and `a.Directions` and replace those with NULL values...

Change this:

```
inner join [SubDivision] s on s.SubDivisionName = a.SubDivision
```

To this:

```
  LEFT
  JOIN [SubDivision] s 
    ON a.SubDivision = s.SubDivisionName
   AND a.SubDivision <> 'N/A'
```

---

or to this (slightly different but equivalent):

```
  LEFT
  JOIN [SubDivision] s 
    ON s.SubDivisionName = a.SubDivision 
   AND s.SubDivisionName <> 'N/A'
```

Comment: I just made an edit, hopefully it is more clear..I tried your suggestion and it gave me back the same results

Comment: That did the trick, its returning a single row now. Thanks, its much appreciated, anyway you can explain why your answer works?

Comment: Explanation: a *left outer* join return rows from the table on left side, even when no "matching" rows are found in the table on the right side.  We added a condition in the ON clause so that rows with 'N/A' in SubDivision will *not* be considered a match.

Comment: Thank you for providing an explanation